# Microchip CanBus Bootloader J1939 - Multiple devices programmed in parallel

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, bootloader

Bonjour,
I have a project where I need a canbus bootloader. The device will be wired on a J1939 bus.

Multiple of my devices can be on the same bus.

Now Microchip gives an application note ([AN247](http://www.t-es-t.hu/download/microchip/an247a.pdf)) but apparently there were problems with it and it was discontinued.

Now they point to the [AN851](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00851b.pdf) but it's an UART bootloader so I guess it needs to be modified.

- Does anyone has experience with the AN247 or AN851 regarding CanBus bootloader ?
- Is there a "ready made" bootloader usable with a little software to program it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a bootloader while other, powered devices are present on the J1939 bus means that your bootloader has to be implemented according to J1939 standards, not after some generic Microchip application note about low-level CAN frames.

Otherwise, you'll have to invent a programming mode where your node is disconnected from the rest of the bus during programming. For example this can be done in hardware by routing the tx/rx signals to a different transceiver, through an analog switch, whenever a button is pressed.

Or if you are certain that nothing in J1939 will collide with your bootloader, maybe just disconnect the node from the J1939 bus during updates. If you are lucky, your bootloader can even co-exist with J1939 if you only use 11 bit identifiers, but that's assuming no other node will go nuts upon receiving such frames.

As for implementing the bootloader, if Microchip provides no code for it, for the specific MCU, or in case there isn't any hardware support on-chip for CAN bootloaders, you have to write it yourself. CAN is as it would happen, far more suitable than UART, since it's more rugged and you get CRC checks free of charge.

Comment: Thanks, why should I need to use 11 bit identifiers I could use extended frames but it will be a little longer to complete the update ?
Can you recommend documents to start with bootloader programming ?

Comment: @Mat Because as far as I know, J1939 only supports 29 bit id and you definitely don't want any identifier collisions between your bootloader and the rest of the bus, since that would be very dangerous: your bootloader could be telling other nodes to do something they shouldn't, or J1939 could start re-programming your node etc. As for documents, just look at established protocols. I once made a bootloader protocol heavily inspired by CANopen SDO for example, with "ping pong" acknowledge etc. How advanced it needs to be depends on your requirements.